# Basic program, but what's the solution?

Tags: java

Main File:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewClass obj = new NewClass();
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter marks of 5 subjects: ");
    obj.c1 = inp.nextInt();
    obj.c2 = inp.nextInt();
    obj.c3 = inp.nextInt();
    obj.c4 = inp.nextInt();
    obj.c5 = inp.nextInt();
    obj.percentage();
}
```

}

Class File:

```
public class NewClass {
int tmarks;
int omarks;
int c1, c2, c3, c4, c5;

NewClass () {
    this.tmarks = 500;
}

omarks = c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 + c5;

public void percentage() {
    double p = (omarks/tmarks) * 100;
    System.out.println("Percentage: " + p);
}
}
```

I am getting an error in the class file "can't find symbol omarks". What's the problem?

Note:
tmarks refers to total marks
omarks refers to obtained marks

Comment: You can't refer to `omarks` outside of a method/constructor.

Comment: You have a stray line of code outside of any method.  It doesn't belong there.

Comment: Have you read the Java manual?

Answer (score 0):

you cant use `omarks` outside constructor or method

```
public void percentage() {
    omarks = c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 + c5;
    double p = (omarks/tmarks) * 100;
    System.out.println("Percentage: " + p);
}
```

Comment: @Mubashir Mazhar did my solution works for you?